# SQL Challenge: Why SQL query does not group according to NULL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I would like to challenge the SQL community here. Let us have the following data and SQL query:

```
create table A
(
    a_id integer unique,
    code int
);

create table B
(
    a_id integer foreign key references A(a_id),
    b_count int
);

insert into A values (1, 20);
insert into A values (3, 30);
insert into A values (null, 30);

insert into B values (1, 100);
insert into B values (1, 120);
insert into B values (null, 200);

select A.a_id, sum(B.b_count) Bsum
from A
left join B on A.a_id = B.a_id
group by A.a_id
```

Why doesn't the SQL query sum the value for the NULL? In other words, why we get

```
a_id    Bsum
---------------
NULL    NULL
1       220
3       NULL
```

instead of

```
a_id    Bsum
---------------
NULL    200
1       220
3       NULL
```

Comment: [Article](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191504(v=sql.105).aspx) about `NULL` values. That should help you to understand why it is not grouped.

Comment: Change left join B on A.a_id = B.a_id into isnull(A.a_id, -1) = isnull(B.a_id, -1) in your on clause and nulliff(A.a_id, -1) in SELECT and you'll get it. On NULL cannot be equal or not equal to another NULL, that is.

Comment: Challenge : What do you think the result will be of the following query : `select case when null = null then 'sure' else 'nope' end as does_null_equal_null`

Comment: Challenge 2 : Predict the result of the following query : `select case when null != null then 'yeah' else 'nay' end as is_null_not_equal_to_null`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This has nothing to do with the `sum()`.  The reason is the `left join` and the way `NULL` works for comparisons.  This is your query:

```
select A.a_id, sum(B.b_count) Bsum
from A left join
     B
     on A.a_id = B.a_id
group by A.a_id;
```

On the rows where `a_id` is `NULL`, the `=` evaluates to `NULL` -- which is not true.  What you seem to want is:

```
select A.a_id, sum(B.b_count) Bsum
from A left join
     B
     on A.a_id = B.a_id or (A.a_id is null and B.a_id is null)
group by A.a_id;
```

Comment: ok, it seems that was not a challenge. I have tried a misleading title, but it did not work :)